# I keep having issues with installing Cardano node on Mac mini2 with M2 processor

Tags: cardano-node, macos

I have conflict involving the cardano-crypto-class package and its dependencies, particularly libblst and vector.

I have included the error code when using cabal build all or cabal build all  --minimize -conflict-set

Anyone had this issue and resolved it?

```
e@E-Mac-mini cardano-node % (cabal build all --minimize-conflict-set
)
Resolving dependencies...
Error: cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: cardano-node-8.7.2 (user goal)
[__1] trying: ouroboros-consensus-0.14.0.0 (dependency of cardano-node)
[__2] trying: cardano-ledger-binary-1.2.1.0 (dependency of
ouroboros-consensus)
[__3] trying: vector-0.13.1.0 (dependency of ouroboros-consensus)
[__4] next goal: cardano-crypto-class (dependency of cardano-node)
[__4] rejecting: cardano-crypto-class-2.1.4.0 (conflict: pkg-config package
libblst-any, not found in the pkg-config database)
[__4] rejecting: cardano-crypto-class-2.1.3.0 (conflict: vector==0.13.1.0,
cardano-crypto-class => vector<0.13)
[__4] skipping: cardano-crypto-class-2.1.2.0, cardano-crypto-class-2.1.1.0,
cardano-crypto-class-2.1.0.2, cardano-crypto-class-2.1.0.1,
cardano-crypto-class-2.1.0.0 (has the same characteristics that caused the
previous version to fail: excludes 'vector' version 0.13.1.0)
[__4] rejecting: cardano-crypto-class-2.0.0.1 (conflict: cardano-ledger-binary
=> cardano-crypto-class>=2.1)
[__4] skipping: cardano-crypto-class-2.0.0.0.1, cardano-crypto-class-2.0.0
(has the same characteristics that caused the previous version to fail:
excluded by constraint '>=2.1' from 'cardano-ledger-binary')
[__4] fail (backjumping, conflict set: cardano-crypto-class,
cardano-ledger-binary, cardano-node, vector)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: ouroboros-consensus, vector,
cardano-node, cardano-crypto-class, cardano-ledger-binary
```

Comment: There are instructions in the `cardano-node` repository for installing `libblst`.

Comment: I am having the same issues.  Were you successful in installing cardano-node?